# How to remove comma in last item of foreachloop in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I tried adding last item logic using if condition, but the code is getting displayed.

My existing code :

```
<script type='application/ld+json'> 
{
  "itemListElement":
[
  @foreach($product->Offers as $offer)
   {
    "@type": "Offer",
    "name": "{{$offer->title}}",
    "price": "{{$offer->displayPrice}}",
   },  
   @endforeach 
 ]
}

}
</script>
```

Comment: store json_result as a object and use it like this - json_result.TrimEnd(',')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this

```
<?php $i = 1; $len = count($product->Offers); ?>
@foreach($product->Offers as $offer)
  {
  "@type": "Offer",
  "name": "{{$offer->title}}",
  "price": "{{$offer->displayPrice}}",
  }<?php if($i < $len){echo ',';} $i++;?>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [`$loop->last()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#the-loop-variable):

```
@foreach($product->Offers as $offer)
{
    "@type": "Offer",
    "name": "{{$offer->title}}",
    "price": "{{$offer->displayPrice}}",
}{{ $loop->last() ? '' : ',' }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. But I learned that when you're using `$loop->last()`, make sure you don't have braces `()` or it'll cause an error.